# SQL BEGINNERS QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns in a table `MEM` and `SUB`, like below

```
| MEM | | SUB |
|-----| |-----|
| 101 | | 101 |
| 201 | | 201 |
| 202 | | 201 |
| 203 | | 201 |
| 301 | | 301 |
```

How do I find out the `SUB` which has no `MEM` beside itself?

How can I query to find the row like `101` and `301`?

PS: I'm new into this, pardon me if the information is incomplete.

Comment: Please, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and come back to edit your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @TheGameiswar I'm more curious in what application does CTRL + SHIFT + L disengage SHOUT MODE?

Comment: @Siyual:In SSMS it works

Comment: Very odd, my comment was removed! (No warning or explanation.) Never mind, it's Friday and soon time to leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all the subs where the Mem and Sub are not the same.

```
SELECT SUB
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE MEM <> SUB
```

This will give you a distinct list of Sub's that, at one point or another, do not have a matching MEM.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUB
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE MEM <> SUB
```

EDIT:

> I WANT TO FIND OUT ALL SUB THATHAS ONLY ONE MEM

This is a *really* simple SQL query.  You'll probably learn it better if you did some research.
Regardless, here is what you need:

```
SELECT SUB
  , COUNT(MEM) AS CountOfMem
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY SUB
     HAVING COUNT(MEM) = 1
```

If this is it, make sure to mark it as answered.

Comment: THAT DOES NOT SOLVE MY ANSWER. I WANT TO FIND OUT ALL SUB THATHAS ONLY ONE MEM